# Django outputs verbose_name in quotes and parentheses in admin panel

Tags: python, django

My problem is the following.

Code:

```
...
class Meta:
    verbose_name = 'сайт',
    verbose_name_plural = '1. Сайт',
...
```

Result:
[image]
[image]

Why Django outputs verbose_name in quotes and parentheses in admin panel?

Comment: Because you have a comma, which makes it as tuple

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the commas after the string values, so that verbose_name and verbose_name_plural are defined as strings.
The trailing comma after the string values turns them into one-element tuples.

```
class Meta:
verbose_name = 'сайт'
verbose_name_plural = '1. Сайт'
```